# Java Generics - Method not applicable for arguments using a child type

Tags: java, generics

I have some code like so:

```
private void processMessage(MessageType message, MessageHandler<MessageType> handler)
{
    handler.handleMessage(message);
}
```

With message handler being an abstract class.

```
public abstract class MessageHandler <T extends MessageType>
{
    public abstract T handleMessage(T message);
}
```

I have a child class:

```
public class FooBarHandler extends MessageHandler<FooBarMessageType>
{
    public FooBarMessageType handleMessage(FooBarMessageType message)
    {...}
}
```

Where FooBarMessageType is a subclass of MessageType.

### Now, when I call processMessage as such:

`processMessage((FooBarMessageType)message, new FooBarHandler());`

I get this error in eclipse:

**The method processMessage(MessageType, MessageHandler) in the type StuffDoer is not applicable for the arguments (FooBarMessageType, FooBarHandler)**

I noticed that when I made the second formal parameter for processMessage raw:

`private void processMessage(MessageType message, MessageHandler handler)`

It *just* becomes a warning. However, the only solution eclipse gives to fix this warning generates the error again.

Comment: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265), note that `FooBarHandler extends MessageHandler<FooBarMessageType>` but `MessageHandler<FooBarMessageType>` is not subtype of `MessageHandler<MessageType>` as explained in linked question.

Comment: What is `StuffDoer`? Your abstract class or your concrete class? If it's your abstract class, then you're using a reference with the wrong generic type.

Comment: @Pshemo that question was entirely unhelpful. However, the issue was resolved by adding a type parameter to processMessage.

private <T extends MessageType> void processMessage(T message, MessageHandler<T> handler)

However you were hasty for flagging and didn't even let me submit a self answer.

Comment: @KyleDumouchelle What makes you think I flag your question? Also how understanding cause of problem is "entirely unhelpful" in finding a way to solve it?